# Two identities in probability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I ma reading the book [An introduction to stochastic processes in physics by Don Stephen Lemons](http://books.google.com/books?id=Uw6YDkd_CXcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=introduction+to+stochastic+process+in+physics&hl=en&ei=Ot6ETrKfPKXz0gH-vJjuDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=introduction%20to%20stochastic%20process%20in%20physics&f=false). I have a question on two  identities.

One identity is the identity (B.3) in Appendix b page 102. How to show that $$ \int\int f(x,v)\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} dx\;dv =\left\langle \frac{df(X,V)}{dt} \right\rangle. $$ Here $X$ is a random variable (position) and $V$ (velocity) is a function of $X$.

The second identity is the first identity of (B.4) which is $$ df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} dX + \frac{\partial f}{\partial V}dV + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial V^2}\frac{(dV)^2}{2}. $$ Why do we have the term $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial V^2}\frac{(dV)^2}{2}$? Thank you very much.

Edit: $X(t)$ is a random variable and $p(x,t)$ is its probability density: the probability of $X(t)$ takes value in $[x, x+dx]$ is $p(x,t)dx$. $dX=\sqrt{\delta^2dt}N_t(0,1)$. $dV=a(X,V)dt + \sqrt{b^2(X,V)dt}N_t(0,1)$. Here $a,b$ are two functions. $N_t(0,1)$ is the random variable with normal distribution. $\langle X \rangle$ is the expectation of X. $f(X,V)$ is a smooth function.

Comment: Since it's physics, would I be right in guessing that $\langle Y\rangle$ means the expected value of $Y$?

Comment: ....and that maybe $p$ means momentum?

Comment: The Google Books page you link to doesn't allow me to view this part of the book. Independent of that, questions should ideally be self-contained. I don't think there's enough context to answer your questions.

Comment: Cliche to say, but second identity reminds Ito lemma. Do you know what is it?

Comment: @user9791 : the first identity it looks like Integration by Parts to me.