# Total derivative and Taylor expansion of a two variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am reading about the difference between total derivative and Taylor expansion from the [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69610/taylor-series-in-two-variables).

As you can see from Bill Cook's answer:

> The total derivative is just the linear approximation of $df$ whereas
> the Taylor series takes into account higher order terms as well.

So does this mean the total derivative is not exact (only an approximation, ignoring higher order terms)?

Comment: What do you mean with exact? The derivative is the best linear approximation of a function at a point, in a very precise sense.

Comment: From Taylor expansion, except two first terms, df also includes higher oder terms as well. But the total derivative doesn't include these terms.

Comment: Also, if df is arbitrary small, then does total derivative and Taylor expansion give the same result?

Comment: Notice in the answer you linked he writes that the total derivative is just the linear approximation of $f$ (rather than df). Taylor expansions (remember order of expansion) are also best approximations of a function in a certain (but mathematically precise) sense. The linear part of a Taylor expansion is precisely the total derivative.

Comment: Thanks, so in that thread question, is it better to express f(x, t) -f(a, b) by something than df because actually df is just the first two terms?

Comment: I'm not sure I undestand this question.

Comment: If we equalize to get an equation from Talylor expansion and total derivative (because both are equal to df), this means that all higher order terms in Taylor is equal to zero. Is this right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48559/discussion-between-fimpellizieri-and-user3126592).