# Taylor expansion of $f(\vec{x}+\vec{a},\vec{y}+\vec{b})$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, taylor-expansion, vector-analysis

Given is a scalar function $f$ of 2 vector arguments, $f=f(\vec{x},\vec{y})$. I was unsure if I can say

$$f:\mathbb{R}^{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$$

but this was the best idea I had and decided to write it here to receive feedback. Under this assumption, it is a Taylor expansion of a function with one vector argument with $2n$ components.

This is an attempt to write the expansion:

Unsure if this expansion is correct... (the expansion is about $\vec{a}=0$, $\vec{b}=0$)

$$f(\vec{x}+\vec{a},\vec{y}+\vec{b})=$$

$$=f(\vec{x},\vec{y})+\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}a_1 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}a_2 + ... +\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}a_n + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_1}b_1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_2}b_2+...+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_n}b_n \right]+...=$$

$$=f(\vec{x},\vec{y})+\left[ (\vec{a}\cdot\nabla_x)f+(\vec{b}\cdot\nabla_y)f \right]+...,$$

where

$$\nabla_x = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2},...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}),$$

$$\nabla_y = (\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1},\frac{\partial}{\partial y_2},...,\frac{\partial}{\partial y_n}),$$

Is the expansion correct? Pls note this is an expansion of a function of 2 vector arguments; the referenced duplicate question is for a function of 2 scalar arguments - the latter doesn't translate directly to this case, since this case is more complex.

Another worry I had is the $\nabla_y$ I got in the expansion. This 'gradient' is very unusual, since mostly we see $\nabla$ to mean what above is written as $\nabla_x$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taylor series in two variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69610/taylor-series-in-two-variables)

Comment: This question is about a function with 2 vector arguments. The one you referenced are 2 scalar arguments

Comment: What you say about the proposed duplicate is correct, but in making two *vector* arguments, you are actually creating a false appearance of generality.  One can just as well combine both vector arguments into a single vector argument, which can have as many components as you like.

Comment: This is what I was worried about. I added more to the text of the question to explain. I wasn't sure I can treat the 2 vector arguments as one. I was worried this could have affected the terms in the expansion.

Comment: The $\nabla_y$ was another worry... Added more text to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define $\vec{z}=(\vec{x},\vec{y})$ and $\vec{c}=(\vec{a},\vec{b})$ then you have 
\begin{align}
f(\vec{x}+\vec{a},\vec{y}+\vec{b})&=f(\vec{z}+\vec{c})\\
&=f(\vec{c})+\langle\nabla f(\vec{c}),~\vec{z}\rangle+\ldots\\
&=f(\vec{a},\vec{b})+\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}\nabla_xf(\vec{a},\vec{b})\\\nabla_yf(\vec{a},\vec{b})\end{pmatrix},~\begin{pmatrix}\vec{x}\\\vec{y}\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle+\ldots\\
&=f(\vec{a},\vec{b})+\langle\nabla_xf(\vec{a},\vec{b}),~\vec{x}\rangle+\langle \nabla_yf(\vec{a},\vec{b}),~\vec{y}\rangle+\ldots\\
&=f(\vec{a},\vec{b})+(\vec{x}\cdot\nabla_x)f(\vec{a},\vec{b})+(\vec{y}\cdot \nabla_y)f(\vec{a},\vec{b})+\ldots
\end{align}
as an expansion around $(\vec{x},\vec{y})=(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you... what is the point of evaluation , is it $\vec{z}=0$

Comment: Yes. This expansion holds in a neighbourhood of $\vec{z}=0$ and gives an expansion of $f$ in a neighbourhood of $(\vec{a},\vec{b})$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Note that the expansion shown here (and in the Question) contains only the first-order derivatives.  If the "..." is intended to represent the rest of the Taylor series expansion, the distinct treatment of the $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ components no longer works; we need the "mixed" partial derivatives combining components from both arguments.  The OP might do well to consider information about this sketched in the "duplicate" linked under the Comments above.