# Algebra, Relationship between multivariable functions with knowns and unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $f$ is a function of two variables, $x$ and $y$. where $x, y$, and $f(x,y)$ are all real numbers. The question is if there is $x_1$ and $x_2$, known numbers, what do we know about the relationship between $f(x_1,y)$ and $f(x_2,y)$, where $y$ is an unknown variable? In particular, let $f(x_1, y_i)$ = $f(x_2,y_j)$, and where $y_i$ and $y_j$ are unknowns, how can we find the relationship between $y_i$ and $y_j$? How do inverse functions work in the way? Can we know more than just treating them as different functions? If this is not possible, what if $f$ is a polynomial?

Thus far, I have observed that it seems replacing all the $x_1$ besides $y$ by $\frac{x_1}{x_2}$ and seems to solve the equation, that is, $y_i = f(\frac{x_1}{x_2},y_j)$ but only for the part related $y_j$, but I still have little clue.

Thanks so much!

Plus, I am not so sure how to accurately word the question.

Comment: You may want to consider Taylor Series for the 2 variables case, see:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69610/taylor-series-in-two-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation between $f(x_1, y)$ and $f(x_2, y)$ could be anything; it will depend on what $f$ is.  For example, for any functions $g(y)$ and $h(y)$, and any distinct $x_1$ and $x_2$, you can construct functions $f$ such that $f(x_1, y) = g(y)$ and $f(x_2, y) = h(y)$: for example,
$$ f(x,y) = \frac{x - x_1}{x_2 - x_1} h(y) + \frac{x - x_2}{x_1 - x_2} g(y) $$

Comment: So this particular f(x,y) is just a construction right? does the condition have to be true for all f? Is this some form of calculus? I cannot see the proof of this condition. Thanks!

Comment: This is just a construction.  There is no "condition" that has to be true for all $f$.  That's the whole point: $f(x_1, y)$ and $f(x_2, y)$ could be anything.

Comment: Thanks. Now thinking from a geometric perspective, taking a 2d plane from a 3d space, it can truly be anything. Very sad and unfortunate. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, another question, in this case, if we have f_inverse(x2, f(x1,y)), are we guaranteed to have some expression of g(x1,x2)*y? That is we should be able to isolate y out? And if so what are the notations used for this process?